# Making sudo call using subxt

Tags: subxt

Good day, I would love to know how to make Sudo calls through subxt library , I can't seem to find a meaningful solution. substrate-api-client has an example on how to make on, but going through the documentation of subxt library, it doesn't show how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a nice test that could be helpful for you to discover how to use `sudo`:

```rust
let call = Call::Balances(BalancesCall::transfer {
    dest: bob,
    value: 10_000,
});

let found_event = cxt
    .api
    .tx()
    .sudo()
    .sudo(call)
    .sign_and_submit_then_watch(&alice)
    .await?
    .wait_for_finalized_success()
    .await?
    .has::<sudo::events::Sudid>()?;
```

Reference: https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/b1b717332eb44af3f992ad4486b0d43a8d1f6d79/subxt/tests/integration/frame/sudo.rs#L42

**Update May 2023:**

Original reference is outdated, new reference here:
https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/81494027c8f5ae62d44883167585d5e557f0fcba/testing/integration-tests/src/frame/sudo.rs#L26

Comment: Original reference code is outdated, new reference here: https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/81494027c8f5ae62d44883167585d5e557f0fcba/testing/integration-tests/src/frame/sudo.rs#L26