# Subxt - Catch Extrinsic Error

Tags: rust, subxt

I am doing sudo call using this example [Making sudo call using subxt](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/632/making-sudo-call-using-subxt):

```
let found_event = api
        .tx()
        .sign_and_submit_then_watch_default(&tx, &bob)
        .await?
        .wait_for_finalized_success()
        .await?
        .has::<rococo::sudo::events::Sudid>()?;
```

I want to throw an error if the extrinsic fails, like in this example someone without sudo privileges (Bob) tries to do the call.

How is the best way using `subxt` to submit an extrinsic to catch and parse the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DispatchError` is returned if the extrinsic failed; this ends up being returned from the above as a `subxt::Error::Runtime(dispatch_error)` after `wait_for_finalized_success`, so you can match on it there and inspect the error to see what went wrong, eg like this pseudocode:

```rust
fn submit_foo() -> Result<bool, subxt::Error> {
    api
        .tx()
        .sign_and_submit_then_watch_default(&tx, &bob)
        .await?
        .wait_for_finalized_success()
        .await?
        .has::<rococo::sudo::events::Sudid>()?
}

if let Err(subxt::Error::Runtime(dispatch_err)) = submit_foo() {
    eprintln!("{dispatch_err}"); 
    // ...or match on it to check for specific variants,
    // DispatchError::Module(module_err) for instance lets
    // you access and work with pallet specific errors.
}
```